# Calling parent method from within a Thread having the same name

Tags: java, multithreading, polymorphism

I need to call a method having the identical name as one of the thread's methods. Stripped down example:

```
class A {
  public void getState() {
    System.out.println("Okay"); //expected to get called
  }
  public void exampleCall() {
    new Thread() {
      @Override public void run() {
        getState(); //gives Thread.getState instead
      }
    }.start();
  } 
}
```

How can I call A.getState() from within run() ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're inside an anonymous inner class, you need to explicitly specify the enclosing outer class with the (somewhat confusing) syntax:

```
A.this.getState();
```

Where `A.this` effectively means "the enclosing `A` instance where this inner class is contained".